# How to get adjacent_post custom_field value

Tags: custom-post-types, single

I would like to customize the prev and next link in a single custom post type page adding to the title the value of one custom field.

Now I'm using this code to get just the title.

```
<?php $prev_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'my-taxonomy-slug' ); ?>
<?php if ( is_a( $prev_post, 'WP_Post' ) ) { ?>
   <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $prev_post->ID ); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem in this way:

I get the custom field data using get_post_meta:

```
<?php $prev_post_type = get_post_meta($prev_post->ID, '_product_type', true);?>
```

and then I use it to customize the link:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $prev_post_title ." ". $prev_post_type ?></a>
```